# Controlling the toy car

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wanted to control a toy car, that has two wires for voltage and two other wires for data in and data out.

I wanted to design, to control the car. The Idea is to control it with the mouse movement. If clicked the car has to start, if clicked twice the car has to stop and should move in left and right directions.

How can this be designed ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will need a microcontroller attached to the car (e.g. Aurdino) and a communication mechanism between your computer and the microcontroller (e.g. Bluetooth or Wi-Fi).

You computer will send the command to the microcontroller which is wired to the car.

You can take a look at this [Bluetooth Controlled Arduino RC Car](http://www.instructables.com/id/Bluetooth-Controlled-Arduino-RC-Car/) to get an idea of how to start.

Comment: Is there a way to control the voltage of the car using the mouse in our system. Do we need a separate microcontroller to do this

Comment: You will write a program on your computer that take the mouse input, send the command to the microcontroller (e.g. over Bluetooth or Wi-Fi), then the microcotnroller will take the action (e.g. change volt or turn motor on) since it is wired to the car

Comment: What if we dont have no micro-controller and we have a motor on the car with 4 wires alone - 2 for volts and two for data. How to control it with the mouse. is it possible to give the signals to the car. Its like writing our own firmware for the car.

Comment: Where the firmware will run?
How do you want to connect your car to the PC?

Comment: The firmware will run on my m/c's kernel.